# Making a stacked bar using different columns in PowerBI

Tags: graph, powerbi

Hi I'm Trying to take data in PowerBI that looks like this

[image: data table]

It basically has several columns with reason for call and the length of time in each one - the time varies

```
Reason1 Reason2 Reason3
--       30 secs   30 secs
60 secs   1 min    ----
---       2 min    ----
```

I need a graph that shows each of these reason split by the length of calls

[image: preferred visual]

thank you (I am also an amateur at PBI so be gentle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to flatten your table into a two column layout. Edit the data source in the Query editor. Starting out, it may look like this:
[image]

Select all columns and click the **Unpivot Columns** command in the **Transform** ribbon. Now your data looks like this:

[image]

Rename "Attribute" to "Category" and rename "Value" to "Time Frame". Filter the Time Frame column and untick Blanks.

[image]

Close and apply the query.

Now you can build a stacked horizontal bar chart. Put "Category" on the Axis and drag "Time Frame" into the values. Since it is text, it will be aggregated with a Count. Drag "Time Frame" into the legend to give each time frame its own colour. Viola!

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: Thanks teylyn. That works great. Much appreciated :)